# Finding Bitcoin address I sent to

Tags: transactions, sending

I sent my Bitcoin to somewhere but I'm not for sure if it was the correct address. Is there a way that I can see what address i sent it to? BTW the transaction was done on coinbase

Comment: If you have the adress where you sent the bitcoins from or a transactionID, you can easily find it out. You can enter an adress on https://blockchain.info/ for example and it tells you all transaction of that adress. Or if you enter the transactionID there, it does also tell you the receiving adress.

Answer (score 1):

You can just login to coinbase then go to Accounts section and choose bitcoin and click on the recent transaction (on the top) and then next to a To (the top text) you will see the address you sent the coin to

Comment: Coinbase usually have a coin sent to many different address which can be hard to find using blockchain.info